# GridView doesn't show my datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have gridview  "gvData" ,i need to fetch the data of my function to gridview :
(I am using c# application)

```
  algorithm.prison obj=new prison();
     gvData.DataSource=  obj.TitForTat();
```

After run i have a empty gridview.
Here is my code:

```
 public DataSet TitForTat()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("myt");
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("iteration", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("prison1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("prison2", typeof (string)));
        prison[] prisons = new prison[2];
        prisons[0] = new prison();
        prisons[1] = new prison();
        //---------------------------
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        prisons[0]._state = "c";
        prisons[1]._state = valueOfState[rd.Next(0, 1)];
        dr["iteration"] = 0;
        dr["prison1"] = "c";
        dr["prison2"] = prisons[1]._state;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        //----------------------
        for (int i = 1; i <= _iteration; i++)
        {
            prisons[0]._state = prisons[1]._state;
            prisons[1]._state = valueOfState[rd.Next(0, 1)];
            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr1["iteration"] =i;

            dr1["prison1"] = prisons[0]._state;
            dr1["prison2"] = prisons[1]._state;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
        }

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have rows in your datatable? You can check the count at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an `ASP.NET`-webforms `GridView`-control you need to call [`DataBind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after you have assigned the `DataSource`:

```
gvData.DataSource = obj.TitForTat();
gvData.DataBind();
```

If it's winforms you have to set the `DataMember` property if you use a `DataSet` instead of a `DataTable`:

```
gvData.DataSource = obj.TitForTat();
gvData.DataMember = "myt";
```

... or use a `DataTable` in the first place:

```
DataSet ds = obj.TitForTat();
if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    gvData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: No it is Form application

Comment: @Spad: I have edited my answer. I would return a `DataTable` if `TitForTat` always creates a single table. A `DataSet` is used normally for multiple tables. That's at least confusing.